# ContentProvider read permission denied

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

I have implemented `ContentProvider` in application.

Application 1: 
 Implemented `ContentProvider` with `permission`.

Application 2 :
Access above `ContentProvider` using `permission`.

Everything working fine if first i install **Application 1** and then install **2 Application**.

> *Issue is here*

If i install **Application 2** first and then install **application 1**.

**then i got read permission error.**

**One solution.**
Add below code in manifest `protection_level = "signature"` then working fine.
But both application is different with different sign.

If anyone know how to solve this issue, Please write the answer ! Response is appreciated

Comment: If they're not signed with the same key, then the app declaring the permission must be installed first. The only way to get around the installation order requirement, AFAIK, is for both apps to declare the permission, but multiple apps cannot do that unless they're signed with the same key.